# Prestashop Module : Add multi select dropdown

Tags: forms, module, field, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a module and I would like to know how to add multiple dropdown with fields_options.

```
        $this->fields_options = array(
        'Test' => array(
            'title' =>  $this->l('Test'),
            'icon' => 'delivery',
            'fields' => array(
                'IXY_GALLERY_CREATION_OCCASION' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('DropdownList'),
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'multiple' => true , // not working
                    'identifier' => 'value',
                    'list' => array(                                  
                            1 => array('value' => 1, 'name' => $this->l('Test 1 ')),
                            2 => array('value' => 2, 'name' => $this->l('Test 2)'))                              
                          )
                ),
            ),
            'description' =>'',
            'submit' => array('title' => $this->l('Save'))
        )
    );
```

Comment: I have just answered similar (or the same) problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731117/prestashop-set-multiple-select-from-the-module-and-get-them-in-the-input Please use this as a guide to satisfy form helper requirements and build your form correct way!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doin if you're meaning that :

```
 $combo = $this->getAddFieldsValues();

   $fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Title'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'label' => $this->l('Nom'),
                    'name' => 'nom_matiere',
                    'options' => array(
                      'query' => $combo[0],
                      'id' => 'id_option', 
                      'name' => 'name'
                        )
                    ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'label' => $this->l('Nom'),
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'options' => array(
                      'query' => $combo[1],
                      'id' => 'id_option', 
                      'name' => 'name'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'name' => $this->l('updateData'),
            )
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer are not correctly .. due its not only dfined the field in the database, also must capture and stored in special way the values, in this example i demostrate to store as "1,2,3,6,8" using a single field

THE COMPLETE CODE AND ALL THE STEPS ARE AT: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?hl=es#!topic/venenuxsarisari/z8vfPsvFFjk

here i put only the most important parts..

as mentioned int he previous link, added a new fiel in the model definition, class and the table sql

**this method permits to stored in the db as "1,2,3" so you can use only a single field** to relation that multiple selected values, **a better could be using groupbox** *but its quite difficult*, take a look to the AdminCustomers controller class in the controllers directory of the prestachop, this has a multiselect group that used a relational table event stored in single field

then in the helper form list array of inputs define a select as:

at the begining dont foget to added that line:

```
// aqui el truco de guardar el multiselect como una secuencia separada por comas, mejor es serializada pero bueh
$this->fields_value['id_employee[]'] = explode(',',$obj->id_employee);
```

this $obj are the representation of the loaded previous stored value when go to edit ... from that object, get the stored value of the field of your multiselect, stored as "1,3,4,6"

and the in the field form helper list of inputs define the select multiple as:

```
            array(
                 'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Select and employee'),
                'name' => 'id_employee_tech',
                'required' => false,
                'col' => '6',
                'default_value' => (int)Tools::getValue('id_employee_tech'),
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => Employee::getEmployees(true), // el true es que solo los que estan activos
                    'id' => 'id_employee',
                    'name' => 'firstname',
                    'default' => array(
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => $this->l('ninguno')
                    )
                )
            ),
```

an then override the post process too

```
public function postProcess()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitTallerOrden'))
    {
        $_POST['id_employee'] = implode(',', Tools::getValue('id_employee'));
    }
    parent::postProcess();
}
```

this make stored in the db as "1,2,3"